# C - How to read a list of space-separated text file of numbers into a List

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I am trying to read a textfile like this

```
    1234567890 1234
    9876543210 22
```

into a List struct in my program. I read in the files via fgets() and then use strtok to seperate the numbers, put them into variables and then finally into the List. However, I find that in doing this and printing the resulting strings, strtok always takes the final string in the final line to be NULL, thus resulting in a segmentation fault.

```
fgets(fileOutput,400,filePointer); //Read in a line from the file

inputPlate = strtok(fileOutput," "); // Take the first token, store     into inputPlate

while(fileOutput != NULL)
{
    string = strtok(NULL," ");
    mileage = atoi(string); //Convert from string to integer and store into mileage

    car = initializeCar(mileage,dateNULL,inputPlate);
    avail->next = addList(avail->next,car,0);

    fgets(fileOutput,400,filePointer);
    inputPlate = strtok(fileOutput," ");
}
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Why would `fileOutput` ever become `NULL`?

Comment: If it reached the end of the file, fileOutput would become null

Comment: Since you are learning, you should break the problem down into smaller subproblems, and make sure you know how to solve each subproblem. (1) Write a function to successfully read each line of a file, and print each line out. (2) Write a function that can successfully parse space separated numbers in a string, and print them out. (3) Write a function that can add a value to a list.

Comment: @SahilAcharya: no, at the end of the file, `fgets()` will return `NULL` but `fileOutput` will be unchanged.  It is probably the name of an array, hence it cannot become `NULL` and the compiler probably would issue a diagnostic if invoked with tha appropriate warning level: `gcc -Wall` or similar.

Comment: It pains me to admit that a solution with `scanf()` would actually be much simpler.

Comment: How? fscanf() only reads until it finds a space right?

Comment: "fscanf() only reads until it finds a space right?" --> No.  depends on the format.

Answer (score 2):

Reading a text file line by line with `fgets()` is good.
Not checking the return value of `fgets()` is weak.  This caused OP's code to process beyond the last line.

```
// Weak code
// fgets(fileOutput,400,filePointer); //Read in a line from the file
// ...
// while(fileOutput != NULL)
// {
```

Better to check the result of `fgets()` to determine when input is complete:

```
#define LINE_SIZE 400
...
while (fgets(fileOutput, LINE_SIZE, filePointer) != NULL) 
{
```

*Then* process the string.  A simple way to assess parsing success to is to append `" %n"` to a `sscanf()` format to record the offset of the scan.

```
   char inputPlate[LINE_SIZE];
   int mileage;
   int n = -1;
   sscanf(fileOutput, "%s%d %n", inputPlate, &mileage, &n);
   // Was `n` not changed? Did scanning stop before the string end?
   if (n < 0 || fileOutput[n] != '\0') {
     Handle_Bad_input();
     break;
   } else {
     car = initializeCar(mileage, dateNULL, inputPlate);
     avail->next = addList(avail->next,car,0);
   }
}
```

Comment: Nice and tricky. I will just add that the space in `" %n"` instructs `fscanf` to skip trailing white space at the end of the line buffer, including the linefeed character. `n` is initalized to `-1` and retains this value if `fscanf()` fails to convert both values, otherwise it receives the number of bytes parsed in the line buffer.

Comment: @chqrlie  That would work for proper input.  I find the `fgets()/sscanf()` handles challenging input better like "def\n456\n".  That is accepted by `fscanf()` as valid but not `fgets()/sscanf()`.

Comment: I definitely agree with that. I'm glad `fscanf()` is once more proven to fail to be the right tool.  It is just a quick and dirty hack with too many quirks.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a simpler parser with `fscanf()`:

```
    FILE *filePointer;
    ... // code not shown for opening the file, initalizing the list...
    char inputPlate[32];
    int mileage;

    while (fscanf(filePointer, "%31s%d", inputPlate, &mileage) == 2) {
        car = initializeCar(mileage, dateNULL, inputPlate);
        avail->next = addList(avail->next, car, 0);
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain how that works? Also fscanf only goes up until there is a space. In trying that implementation, I find that the plate number overwrites all values with the last plate number

Comment: @SahilAcharya: `fscanf()` keeps parsing for as long as there are space separated plate names and mileage numbers. If you provided a complete test case, one could check why you observe other problems.

Comment: What would that require, the way of a test case?

Comment: Please learn how to create an MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There might be other issues in the code you did not post that cause the bad behavior you observe.